# launch function B 3 seconds after function A finish (using MBProgressHUD)

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, function, mbprogresshud

I want to show a UIActionSheet a couple seconds after a function finishes which is done with function B.

it works great if i do it like this:

```
main function
{
[self function A]
[self performSelector:@selector(function B) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}
```

but i am using MBProgressHUD as an activity indicator:

```
main function
{
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(funcion A) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
[self performSelector:@selector(function B) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}
```

does not work, function B never gets called. if i switch it to [self function B] it will be called. i'm guessing this is an issue with threading that i don't understand yet. if i use [self performSelectorOnMainThread] it will call function B but it doesn't look like i can delay that one.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the HUD is called on the main thread and is not set to wait. So it fires off your functionA, then immediately calls your performSelector for function B. If you want function B to perform correctly, you will have to call it at the end of function A.